# How do I set default values for the header section of all emails in a rails mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a mailer defined as such:

```
class AdminMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "site@myapp.com", to: Rails.application.config.admin_email
  def notify
     mail subject "We have a new uer
  end 
end
```

and I need to add a default header with Precedence = "bulk".
If I add `headers["Precedence"] = "bulk"` into the **notify()** method, this works. But I would like this to be the default for all methods.
I tried

```
default from: "site@itcentralstation.com", headers: {"Precedence" => "bulk"}

default from: "site@itcentralstation.com", "headers" => {"Precedence" => "bulk"}
```

and both times I got the error: **NoMethodError - undefined method `encoding' for {"Precedence"=>"bulk"}:Hash:**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
default from: "site@itcentralstation.com", "Precedence" => "bulk"
```

Comment: Also, should you want this to work across multiple mailers, try having AdminMailer inheriting from a class which you define(which inherits from ActionMailer). There you can set these defaults for multiple mailer classes.